# Storing Values When a Macro Ends for powerpoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm refering to the following explanation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/word/concepts/miscellaneous/storing-values-when-a-macro-ends

How can I adapt the following code to be used in powerpoint?
Replacing `ActiveDocument` by `ActivePresentaiton` doesn't seem to do the trick.

```
Sub AddDocumentVariable()
 ActiveDocument.Variables.Add Name:="Age", Value:=12
End Sub
Sub UseDocumentVariable()
 Dim intAge As Integer
 intAge = ActiveDocument.Variables("Age").Value
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How you store the information will depend on how much is to be stored and what you need to do with it later.  While I wouldn't recommend using the registry, a text file would make a good permanent record that can be appended to.

Or you can store the information in .Tags:

```
Sub AddTag()
  ActivePresentation.Tags.Add "Name", "12"
End Sub

Sub ReadTag()
  MsgBox ActivePresentation.Tags("Name")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot replace `ActiveDocument` with `ActivePresentaiton` directly for your case. `ActivePresentaiton` does not have the `.Variables` property.

My suggestion for Powerpoint is to save your data in a .txt file, so you can access it later, or add your variables to the registry. Read [this link](http://www.pptalchemy.co.uk/vba_data.html) here.

I would suggest doing more research, and posting your code so we can better help understand your entire problem.